# Linking error while compiling opencv with cuda on high sierra

Tags: macos, opencv, macos-high-sierra

I am getting a linking error while compiling opencv with cuda on Mac OS X high Sierra (10.13.6).

Error message:

```
[ 21%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudev.dylib
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/unknownn/opencv/-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda'
ld: library not found for -llib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_cudev.4.0.1.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/cudev/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have already tried pretty much every cuda (9, 9.2, 10) and opencv (3.4, 4.0.1) version. Also I am aware that every cuda version requires a specific Xcode version.

I have also tried various cmake versions

I checked for the correct cuda paths in ccmake.

I dont know why the ld warnings appear since /usr/local/cuda exist.

What is -llib?

Comment: What was your `cmake` command?

Comment: cmake -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=OFF -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 -DCUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as well, what's interesting is that the problem does not appear to be with OpenCV, but with `cmake`.

The FindCUDA that comes with `cmake` seems to be broken, producing that strange `-llib`. You can see it during the cmake run as well as:

```
Extra dependencies:          cudart_static lib nppc nppial nppicc nppicom nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda
```

(Note the second element "lib", the last two -L... elements will cause problem when you do make install as well)

However, the opencv source package comes with FindCUDA.cmake files that seem to work.

Assuming:
cmake is in /usr/local/share/cmake
opencv source is in ~/opencv

Do the following first:

```
mv /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/FindCUDA* /tmp # Or some other back up location
cp -r ~/opencv/cmake/FindCUDA* /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules
```

Then run your build steps as before (`cmake ...`, `make ...`, `make install`), and hopefully it will work this time (it did for me).

As far as I can tell, cmake has deprecated FindCUDA.cmake, so I'm guessing it won't get fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by Jack Leow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56860085/5160481) was very usefull, but I had to make farther investigation, because indeed his solution doesn't work any more.

Finally I have found [this answer on opencv github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14909#issuecomment-508645243) by [alalek](https://github.com/alalek). If in short, he proposes to add following cmake definition:

```sh
-DOPENCV_CUDA_FORCE_BUILTIN_CMAKE_MODULE=ON
```

This solution works to me.

P.S.: Currently I managed to solve few more issues on my way to get awesome opencv build. But currently build is in progress (44%) hope it will be finished in next half an hour, haha!

Answer (score 0):

sorry, although this workaround worked once with opencv-3.4.9 / XCode8.2 (Clang 8) / CMake 3.12, now the switching of the FindCUDA files does not work anymore with the combination

opencv-3.4.9 / XCode9.2 (Clang 9) / CMake 3.16 with the following error:

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake3.16/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:416 (file):
file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):
/Users/filippo/opencv- 3.4.9/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_genera ted_gpu_mat.cu.o.depend
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1363 (cuda_include_nvcc_dependencies)
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1650 (CUDA_WRAP_SRCS)
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:1663 (cuda_compile_base)
cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake:262 (CUDA_COMPILE)
cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1513 (ocv_cuda_compile)
cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:927 (ocv_add_library)
cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:848 (_ocv_create_module)
modules/core/CMakeLists.txt:81 (ocv_create_module)
```

I had to update XCode to the 9.2 because I had a "nullability" compiling error in the building opencv-3.4.9 probably caused by Clang.

Comment: I believe the problem is CMake 3.16. I had to rebuild OpenCV with CUDA 10.2 / Xcode 10.2.1 / macOS 10.13.6, and my build completed, but I had to revert to CMake 3.14.5 (3.14.7 or 3.15.x may work as well, but 3.17.x definitely did not - I just went straight to 3.14.5 because that was the version that last worked for me).